# Using authorization filter in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I have an asp.net Mvc4 application in which i'd like to use the authorization filter to secure my application so i added  this snippet to my `web.config` file

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl=""~/Home/Login" />
    </authentication>
    </system.web>
```

In the controller :

```
 public ActionResult Login() {
           return View(new User());
       }
      [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Login(User u)
       {
           return View(new User());
       }


      [Authorize(Roles ="admin")]
       public ActionResult AdminSpace()
       {
           return View();
       }
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
       public ActionResult UserSpace()
       {
           return View();
       }
```

And finally the `user` class

```
 public class User
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Mdp { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public static bool Authentificate(string login, string password){

            if (login == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {

            }

            if (login == "user" && password == "user")
            {

            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

To simply the issue , i'd like to add the role of admin to the account (admin/admin ) and the role user to the account( user/ user).

- How can i change my code to reach this goal?
- What are the best practices to authentificate users in asp.net internet application?

Comment: Why are you creating your own authentication system? MVC 4 comes with all of this created for you right out of the box.. there is alot involved with web security and this does not even come close.

Comment: I need to add differents user's roles because my application have many spaces and i don't like to add a list of authorized users in the web.config because this list is dynamic

Comment: You can add roles to the standard MVC auth that comes with MVC out of the box. It would be much more preferable than the implementation that you are attempting to build.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul can you explain more plz in a snippet example, i think i didn't understand you

Comment: I found a good solution here: [link](http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/)